# d3js: Unable to place horizontally bars within the axis

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning to make charts in d3 from scratch without taking someone else code and modifying it. I can successfully create a x & y axis vertical bar chart. But when it comes to transform the same chart to horizontal bar chart I end up in a mess. Here is my code so far:

```
var data = [{
  name: "China",
  value: 1330141295
}, {
  name: "India",
  value: 1173108018
}, {
  name: "Indonesia",
  value: 242968342
}, {
  name: "Russia",
  value: 139390205
}];
//set margins
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 40
};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//set scales & ranges
var yScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height]).padding(0.1)
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width])
//draw the svg
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left * 2 + "," + margin.top + ")")
//load the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
});

//set domains

xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.population
})])

yScale.domain(data.map(d => d.name))

//add x & y Axis

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d.name))
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d.name))
  .attr("x", d => width - xScale(d.population))
  .attr("width", yScale.bandwidth())
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: as soon I add an answer I violate your "I do not want to use somebodies code"

Comment: Hi rioV8, I do not want you to re-write / modify  the code I posted, I just want some explanation in English language not in code language. My question is only for learning purpose. Regards.

Comment: Here are a few things you're doing wrong: 1. **There is no `population` in the data (it's `value`)** 2. You're appending bars to the x-axis (<g>). 3. As you're building a horizontal bar chart, shouldn't the height be equal to the band width? 4. To start the bar from the y-axis, try changing the `x` to 0. 5. While you make the above changes, what do you think the width should be then?

Comment: @Shashank,  Thanks a lot! I managed to generate chart. However, there's one bar which doesn't get visible, as I'm setting the `width` of bars as a function of  the scale for the `x` axis and this is:  `xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,  width]).domain([d3.min(data, d=> d.value), d3.max(data, d=> d.value)])`and the lowest value in my array gets its corresponding `width` mapped to 0.  Then I thought to set the domain to `[margin.left , width]` but didn't work either because the `x` axis itself is also moved `margin.left` to the right. Can you please tell me how to deal with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would get mapped to 0 as the `xScale(Russia's population) === 0`. Why not set the domain to `[0, d3.max(data, d=> d.value)]` as you have in the question here? That would mean a reasonable width to the `rect`s (unless value would be <=0 which wouldn't be the case here).

Comment: Thank you @Shashank! it worked perfectly and the best par is that thanks to you I understood the logic behind it. Thanks (y)

Comment: Cool. That was important! Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a lot of things in your code.

TL;DR

- change `value` to `population` in the array
- scales are used to convert values to proportional pixel values
- `height` is the vertical size of an element. you should use `yScale(d.name)`
- `width` is the horizontal size of an element. you should use `xScale(d.population)`
- `y` is the vertical position of an element. you should use `yScale.bandwidth()`
- `x` is the vertical position of an element. you should use `0`
- use `selectAll("rect")` on a new appended `g` or the `svg` element not the same `g` element that has the axises on it
- add `fill` attribute so that your rects have color

You have the population field labelled `value` but you're calling `population` through out the code to use it. So replace value with population in your data objects.

Next you need to change the way you're setting up the rects. use selectAll on the `svg` element directly or append another `g` to the `svg` element and add the rects on that element. Right now your code attempts to add the rects to the same `g` element as the x axis.

Make sure you are setting the attributes of the rects correctly. Height is the size in pixels of the rect element not the position. `y` is the position of the rects vertically from the top downwards. this means the `height` attribute should use `yScale(d.name)` and `width` should use `xScale(d.population)` because they are the width and length of the rectangles, or `rect` elements. `x` and `y` are the coordinate positions of the element from the top left corner of the `svg` element. Use them to determine the starting position of the top left pixel of your rects. You should have `y` as `yScale.bandwidth()` and `x` as `0`.